# How to change ?url= into a node structured route

Tags: node.js, express

So I am currently doing the following.

> `http://example.com/podcast?url=https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/QWA/S01/QWAS1E1.mp3`

However, I want to do the following.

> `http://example.com/podcast/https://storage.googleapis.com/XXX/XXX/S01/QWAS1E1.mp3`

I understand that `router.get('/:url', (req, res) => {`
should allow me to send http://example.com/podcast/http

I also understand that

```
router.get('/:url*', (req, res) => {
```

should also allow http://example.com/podcast/https://storage.googleapis.com/XXX/XXX/S01/QWAS1E1.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

The `*` enables the route to be called for your url and the `req.params` would let you read the the inner url passed along with.

Try the following route with `http://example.com/podcast/https://storage.googleapis.com/XXX/XXX/S01/QWAS1E1.mp3`

```
router.get('/prodcast/*', async (req, res, next) => {

    console.log(req.query.params);    //https://storage.googleapis.com/XXX/XXX/S01/QWAS1E1.mp3


    res.status(200).send('ok');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define you router like

```
app.get('/podcast/:url(*)', (req, res) =>
```

`:url(*)` instead of `:url*`

Now you can get your url via `req.params.url`.

You can use your way (`:url*`), but you need some trick to get your url data, in this case, `req.params` will be like

```
{
  0: "//example.com/podcast/https://storage.googleapis.com/XXX/XXX/S01/QWAS1E1.mp3",
  url: "http:"
}
```

Then, the url data will be: `const url = req.params.url + req.params[0];`